# get the biggest not overlapping objects algorithm (x, y, width, height)

Tags: c#, algorithm

I've a array with objects. Every class have x, y, width, height property.
Need to get all the biggest not overlapping on the vertical and on the horizontal side. 
I've already solve this, but my algorithm is slow and pretty ugly. 
How can i solve this elegant ? If it's possible for you, please show me some code
not just mathematics stuff.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

---

So the output have to be

Vertical objects 1, 4, 8

Horizontal objects 0, 1, 2

**Example**

```
___________
var 0 = new MyClass(X:0, Y:0, Width:10, Height:3);
var 1 = new MyClass(X:10, Y:0, Width:10, Height:5);
var 2 = new MyClass(X:20, Y:0, Width:10, Height:2);

pick 1 because
0.Height < 1.Height

var 3 = new MyClass(X:0, Y:3, Width:10, Height:6);
var 4 = new MyClass(X:0, Y:5, Width:10, Height:3);
var 5 = new MyClass(X:0, Y:2, Width:10, Height:8);

pick 4 because
3 and 5 are overlapping with 1.
...............
```

There can be free space between elements.

Comment: How about showing us your code so we can tell you why it is slow?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on your requirements.  Why 1,4,8 and not 0,3,8 for vertical?  Why not 3,1,5 for horizontal?  What is biggest?  Width? Height? Area?  Are there always exactly 9 elements in your array?  Will they always fit nicely together like a puzzle as you have it?

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping? Are some of these objects on top of each other? (I mean in the z-order)

Comment: @Cicada Sorry it make no sense in this case. My code is to abstruse. There are many, many relations to other classes. Because of these relations its to big, too. It was a bad design and it will just confuse.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I mean 1 is the first biggest vertical element. It overlapped with 3 and 5 by y coordinate. There is no z coordinate.

Comment: We cannot help you with your algorithm without being able to see it.

Comment: @gilly3 0,3,7 are not the values for vertical because i start with the  lowest x coordinates and the greatest height. 0 element height is smaller than 1 element height. The next is 4 because 3 and 5 are overlapping by the y coordinate. Than 8 because height is greater, too. There are variable elements in the array and yes it will always fit together.

Comment: What is the requirement? Largest contiguous region along a given axis? You mention that some may have spaces between them. Does that mean you want to disallow gaps along a particular axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate `Top` and `Bottom` values for each `MyClass`.

Use a `Boundary` variable, initializing it to `0`.

1. Pick an element with biggest height (`Bottom` - `Top`), whose `Top` = `Boundary`. If some elements are ax equo (same `Top`, same height), pick the one on the left.
2. Shift (set) `Boundary` to `Bottom` of this element (this ensures that the next element you pick will not overlap with this one).
3. Go to `1`.

When going horizontally, just use `Left` instead of `Top` etc.

Given your requirements (*"Will they always fit nicely together like a puzzle as you have it?"* - you reply *"yes it will always fit together"*) it would work as you described: 1, 4, 8.

**Edit:** okay. Then we just pick an element whose Top is GREATER or equal than the previous element's Bottom.

Something along the lines of:

```
public List<MyClass> GetBiggestNotOverlappingVertically(ICollection<MyClass> elements)
{
    var result = new List<MyClass>();
    var boundary = 0;
    var stop = false;
    Func<MyClass, MyClass, bool> inTheSameLane = (first, second) =>
        ((first.Left >= second.Left && first.Left <= second.Right) ||
        (first.Right <= second.Right && first.Right >= second.Left));
    while (!stop)
    {
        var nextElement = (from element in elements
                           where element.Top >= boundary &&
                                // and where we are NOT "jumping over" any element in the same lane:
                                // there's no element between the two (in the same lane, that is)
                                !(from otherElement in elements
                                  where otherElement != element &&
                                  inTheSameLane(element, otherElement) &&
                                  otherElement.Top >= boundary &&
                                  otherElement.Bottom <= element.Top
                                  select otherElement).Any()
                           orderby element.Height descending,
                                   element.Left ascending
                           select element).FirstOrDefault();
        stop = nextElement == null;
        if (!stop)
        {
            result.Add(nextElement);
            boundary = nextElement.Bottom; 
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: sorry ! I've made a mistake its don't always fit together. There can be space between elements.

Comment: Okay... I adjusted my suggestion accordingly and I put together some sample code for a try.

Comment: @Vibo, how does that help if you have a stack of small items that is bigger than a single item, all starting from the top?

Comment: @MSN I don't get what you mean.

Comment: thanks i will try it. had a blockhead. its seems not really complicated.

Comment: No problem, I hope it's helpful. Not complicated but perhaps I don't grasp the problem fully, I'll have another look if that's the case.

Comment: @Vigo, lets say you have 5 1x2 blocks arranged on the left side of this space, and a 1x9 block. Your solution will start with the 1x9 block; if you started with the 1x2 blocks, you would find a greater span of blocks along the Y axis.

Comment: @MSN you're correct, but that's not how I understand the requirements given by OP. He explicitly says he picks element 1 (in the example) because it's the heighest one - not because picking it will get you the highest "tower" ultimately.

Comment: @Vibo, Ahhh... in that case, you are correct. Good thing I didn't downvote.

Comment: But it still isn't right... if empty space is allowed between the elements, then picking the next one among those whose `Top` >= the `Bottom` of the previous element, will make us "jump over" some elements. But how do we determine whether it's legal to jump over an element or not? We can't say if it is "in our way", because we're not required to stay in one lane (axis). The problem seems not to be defined well to me.

Answer (score 1):

I "draw" it an get the visible size

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<myClass> data = new List<myClass>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        data.Add(new myClass() { Height = 3, Width = 10, X = 0, Y = 0, Id = 1 });
        data.Add(new myClass() { Height = 5, Width = 10, X = 10, Y = 0, Id = 2 });
        data.Add(new myClass() { Height = 2, Width = 10, X = 20, Y = 0, Id = 3 });
        data.Add(new myClass() { Height = 6, Width = 10, X = 0, Y = 3, Id = 4 });
        data.Add(new myClass() { Height = 3, Width = 10, X = 0, Y = 5, Id = 5 });
        data.Add(new myClass() { Height = 8, Width = 10, X = 0, Y = 2, Id = 6 });

        List<myClass> result = GetVisualRegions(data);

        var dataSortW = from item in result
                        orderby item.Width descending
                        select item;
        var dataSortH = from item in result
                        orderby item.Height descending
                        select item;
        Console.WriteLine("Data sorted by Width");
        foreach (var item in dataSortW)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Data sorted by Height");
        foreach (var item in dataSortH)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static List<myClass> GetVisualRegions(List<myClass> data)
    {
        int maxX = data.Max(obj => obj.X + obj.Width);
        int maxY = data.Max(obj => obj.Y + obj.Height);
        int[,] dataOverlapping = new int[maxX, maxY];
        List<myClass> result = new List<myClass>();
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            myClass tmpItem = new myClass();
            bool yColected = false;
            int xdata = item.X + item.Width;
            int ydata = item.Y + item.Height;
            int id = item.Id;
            tmpItem.Id = item.Id; ;
            for (int posY = item.Y; posY < ydata; posY++)
            {
                int width = 0;
                for (int posX = item.X; posX < xdata; posX++)
                {
                    if (dataOverlapping[posX, posY] <= 0)
                    {
                        dataOverlapping[posX, posY] = id;

                        width += 1;
                        if (yColected == false)
                        {
                            yColected = true;
                            tmpItem.Height += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                yColected = false;

                if (tmpItem.Width < width)
                    tmpItem.Width = width;
            }
            if ((tmpItem.Height > 0) && (tmpItem.Width > 0))
                result.Add(tmpItem);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
public class myClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

}